How does one integrate across a finite line in the complex plane?
In real variables, you can integrate a function of a single variable over a line, like from the numbers $a$ to $b.$ But let's say you wanted to integrate a complex-valued function, like $z^2$, can you do this "from" the number $1 + 2i$ to the number $3 + 4i$? How does the integral know how to interpolate? If the interpolation is linear, where and how is this accounted for? Does the path need to maybe be parameterized?

Yes, you could parametrize the linear path.  Complex integrals are line integrals.  [Your integral may not be path-independent, so you have to specify the exact path.]

Okay, so in general the path is unspecified, you must necessarily parameterize it, and then integrate according to that parameter? Or...how does this work? I can't remember anymore how this works, and I'm unsure what to look up to answer this specific question anyways.

Try looking up "contour integration".

Well, I'm familiar with integrating in a circle because it has convenient properties. But I don't want to be limited to a circle, I'd like to be able to integrate along all kinds of parameterized paths. How do I do that though?
